# Why does postgres group null values?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, null

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE wirednull (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    value bigint,
    CONSTRAINT wirednull_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO wirednull (id,value) VALUES (1,null);
INSERT INTO wirednull (id,value) VALUES (2,null);

SELECT value FROM wirednull GROUP BY value;
```

Returns one row, but i would expect two rows since

```
SELECT * 
FROM wirednull a 
LEFT JOIN wirednull b 
  ON (a.value = b.value)
```

does not find any joins, because null!=null in postgres

Comment: They are not really "equal" in the group. It's just a group for anything that can't be compared with `=` (which in this case means all null values)

Comment: Because the grouping is not defined as equality within the group, but as difference with other groups.

Comment: is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: `ON (a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value)` would actually give you 4 result rows.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/l03130307b3688a1e21f0%40%5B147.233.159.109%5D - but I'd like to see where it is sayd that `standard is clear about each of these things
separately. It absolutely says that nulls should be grouped together, and
it absolutely says that the comparison operator should not.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [SQL wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#When_two_nulls_are_equal:_grouping.2C_sorting.2C_and_some_set_operations) :

### When two nulls are equal: grouping, sorting, and some set operations

> Because SQL:2003 defines all Null markers as being unequal to one another, a special definition was required in order to group Nulls together when performing certain operations. SQL defines "any two values that are equal to one another, or any two Nulls", as "not distinct".[20] This definition of not distinct allows SQL to group and sort Nulls when the GROUP BY clause (and other keywords that perform grouping) are used.

This wasn't the question:

<strike>Because `null = null` or `something = null` return `unknown` not `true/false`</strike>

So:

```
ON (a.value = b.value)
```

Doesn't match.

Comment: but why does it match while grouping?

Comment: which function is used to compare while grouping? or is null==null hardcoded while grouping? is there any doc about hat?

Comment: @joop but the question is why are they group together if they arent "equal" the answer is as OP suggested is "hard coded"

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : yes I understand that. I should have commented under the OQ.